# Batch processing Surface volume calculation in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, 3d-analyst, batch, hydrology

I'm trying to collect the 2D area, 3D area and volume of a given basin at 0.5 meter increment in plane height, but since I want to graph the relationship between plane height and the areas and volume, i want to collect many many points.

Doing this one by one is tedious. I'm wondering whether there is a python code that allows me to process a whole bunch of plane heights at once and congregate results in one .txt file or excel file.

currently, the code I'm using is

```
import arcpy
text="c:\\document\riverside\text.txt"
arcpy.SurfaceVolume_3d("watersheddem",text,"BELOW",250,1,1)
```

but this code only allows me to read result on the side bar, when i actually check the text.txt file it is empty even when my arcpy.surfacevolume_3d was ran successfully.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  It may just be the way you have formed your pathname - try `text=r"c:\document\riverside\text.txt"`.

Comment: see your GeoNet post for further comments

Answer (score 2):

This tool will loop through a range of user-defined values and write the outputs to a text file.  You can get the Arctoolbox tool version here https://github.com/gerry1138/ArcGIS-Loop-Surface-Volumes

```
try:
    import sys, arcpy, traceback
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

    arcpy.AddMessage( "Multi-Volumes for ArcGIS 10")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Loop the 3D Analyist Surface Volume tools for a range of values...")


    def GetValues(themessage, x):
        thevaluesatx = str(x)
        themessage = themessage.split("\n")
        thevalues = themessage[2].split("  ")
        for item in thevalues:
            thevalue = item.split("=")
            thevalue = thevalue[-1]
            thevaluesatx = thevaluesatx + "," + str(thevalue)
        thevaluesatx = thevaluesatx +"\n"
        arcpy.AddMessage(thevaluesatx)
        return thevaluesatx


    #My_txt = r"Z:\GISpublic\GerryG\aaaa.txt"
    #My_surface= r"I:\SurfaceModels\USGS_DEM\ldeltagrid5ft"
    #direction = "above"
    #startingplane = 0
    #z = 1
    #y = .5
    #q = 2

    My_surface= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    My_txt = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    direction = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

    startingplane = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3))
    z = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4))
    graduations = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5))
    endingplane = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6))

    direction  = direction.upper()
    f = open(My_txt,'a')
    f.writelines(r"elevation, 2d_area, 3d_area, volume" + "\n")

    arcpy.AddMessage("Please wait, this script is processing...")

    if direction == "BELOW":
        arcpy.AddMessage("startingplane = " +str(startingplane))
        arcpy.AddMessage("endingplane = " +str(endingplane))

        while startingplane > endingplane:
            arcpy.AddMessage("Getting Results...")
            result = arcpy.SurfaceVolume_3d(My_surface, "", direction, startingplane, z)
            thevaluesatx = GetValues(result.getMessages(0), startingplane)
            f.writelines(thevaluesatx)

            startingplane = startingplane - graduations

    if direction == "ABOVE":
        arcpy.AddMessage("Executing above...")
        x = startingplane
        while startingplane < endingplane:
            result = arcpy.SurfaceVolume_3d(My_surface, "", direction, startingplane, z)
            thevaluesatx = GetValues(result.getMessages(0), startingplane)
            print thevaluesatx
            f.writelines(thevaluesatx)

            startingplane = startingplane + graduations


    f.close()

    arcpy.AddMessage("Finished without errors!")

except arcpy.ExecuteError: 
    msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2) 
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)  

except:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    msgs = "ArcPy ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)
```